# BigQuery Left join on list of strings returns null

Tags: google-bigquery

I couldn't come up with a good title for this question. Sorry about that.

From a collection of emails, I want to check which emails are from a list of unknown users. However, when I do a left join like below, the join doesn't seem to match and I get NULL values in tb2.email instead.

```
#StandardSQL 
with unknown_addresses AS (
  select 'test1@gmail.com' AS email
  union all
  select 'test2@gmail.com' AS email
  union all
  select 'test3@gmail.com' AS email
  union all
  select 'test4@gmail.com' AS email
  union all
  select 'test5@gmail.com' AS email
),

all_emails_received as (
  SELECT
    SUBSTR(REGEXP_EXTRACT(mystring, r"[a-z.@\-]+"), 4) as email,
    content
  FROM
    foobar 
)

SELECT tb1.email, tb1.content, tb2.email AS unknown_email 
FROM all_emails_received tb1 
  LEFT JOIN unknown_addresses tb2 
    ON tb1.email = tb2.email
```

How do I make the join condition work?

I don't want to create a new table just to store unknown_addresses.

(Edit) Added sample of raw data

```sql
| email           | content     | 
| --------------- | ----------- | 
| test1@gmail.com | Hello there | 
| gary@gmail.com  | test test   | 
| abc@gmail.com   | foobar      |
```

What I'm currently getting

```sql
| email           | content     | unknown_email   | 
| --------------- | ----------- | --------------- |
| test1@gmail.com | Hello there | null            |
| gary@gmail.com  | test test   | null            |   
| abc@gmail.com   | foobar      | null            |
```

Desired outcome

```sql
| email           | content     | unknown_email   | 
| --------------- | ----------- | --------------- |
| test1@gmail.com | Hello there | test1@gmail.com | 
| gary@gmail.com  | test test   | null            |   
| abc@gmail.com   | foobar      | null            |
```

Edit 2: Still not working. I added the substr and regexp filter in there. Not sure if that's what's affecting my result.

Comment: can you give us a sample tb1, and a sample desired result?

Comment: Your code should be working. Can you give some examples of your data?

Comment: In order to reproduce your error and figure it out, I would need a piece of dummy data. Could you please provide that?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Added sample data and desired outcome

Comment: After analyzing and reproducing your case, I was able to retrieve the desired output from you raw data. The only thing I changed in your code was the PK you use in your left join to **_ON tb1.email = tb2.email_** instead of  _**ON tb1.agent_email = tb2.email**_. Please let me know if after changing it worked.

Comment: still does not work. not sure if this matters but in my original query, I used regex to extract the email from a longer string. I just added this to the description too. would this affect the join?

Comment: @angsty_robot that might be the case then because with your sample data I was able to get the desired output. I will have a look in your regex exp now.

Comment: I don't think incorrect regex exp is the issue here. When I print tb1.email from the second CTE, I get the desired outcome (ie., test1@gmail.com) correctly. However, when I print both columns side by side in the third CTE, I keep getting null values.

Comment: @angsty_robot, I had the same error as you had using your query. Although, I changed this line _SUBSTR(REGEXP_EXTRACT(mystring, r"[a-z.@\-]+"), 4) as email_ to **REGEXP_EXTRACT(email, r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.+[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$") as email** . I also used the PK that I informed above. Could you please try that ? Let me know if it worked.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Hey Alex, it worked. I realised there was whitespace surrounding my original regexp that didn't get displayed on BQ's view table, but your regexp removed it. So, thank you! Would you like to post your comment as a solution so I can you an upvote?

Comment: @angsty_robot, I am glad I could help. I will post as an answer. I would be pleased if you can accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: @angsty_robot, I have uploaded the answer. Can you please accept and upvote the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce you error with you raw data. I realized that the problem was in you **REGEX EXP**. Therefore, it should be:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(email, r"^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.+[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$") as email
```

Changing the code with the above line, you should be able to retrieve the desired output.

I am glad I could help you.